# Create dask list for dask dataframe column

Tags: python, list, dask

I want to have a list of the unique values of a column of dask dataframe  . Using compute() after unique() is working but it takes a lot of time and there is no paralleling.

```py
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18, 25, 31]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

list=df.Name.unique().compute()
```

What I am trying to have is a dask list without using the compute having

```py
list=['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack']
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? How many rows does your real dataframe have?

Comment: Millions and that' the reason I use dask instead of pandas.

Comment: It should parallelise. If you visualise the task graph with `task = df.Name.unique(); task.visualize()` you'll see it does. Are you sure that is the part that is slow? Are you really reading the data into a pandas dataframe first and then into a Dask dataframe?

Comment: I just read it in pandas here for the purpose of the example. My problem is not that the df.Name.unique() is slow, but I need to make it a list so I can iterate through it and trying to find out how to create a dask list. The list=df.Name.unique().compute().tolist() is really slow

Comment: Ok. I suppose the answer depends what you want to do with the list?

Comment: If you need to iterate using other data inside the dataframe isn't better a groupby?

Comment: why is better a groupby?

Answer (score 1):

When you operate on text data, Pandas isn't able to release the GIL, so the default thread-based parallelism will not be effective.  You should consider using processes instead.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#processes-and-threads